# Setting and displaying event time to the client at different time zones

Tags: timezone, utc

I was wondering what is the best way to deal with time zones.

Let's say `user1` wrote a message to `user2`

Now `user1` is at `UTC + 2` and `user2` is at `UTC -2` and let's say server sets time in `UTC +1`

So how would i deal with all this difference in time zones?

I am writing jquery plugin which is going to update time how long ago something happened, my best guess is to set server to `UTC 0` and then just calculate time difference based on client time zone, but is there a way to get client time zone, or maybe im doing it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use epoch time (UTC+00) from top to bottom and ignore time zones. Assume browser/OS time zone is correct. This means every message sent and received has a timestamp in the form of number of milliseconds since epoch, generated using `new Date().getTime()`.

My current time is:

```
Thu Oct 18 2012 22:07:11 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

or:

```
1350590831507
```

CEST is UTC+02. The latter form interpreted on target computer (`new Date(1350590831507)` with UTC-0200) will be:

```
Thu Oct 18 2012 18:07:11 GMT-0200
```

But it's still the same date (point in time)! If ten seconds later you compare this timestamp with `new Date().getTime()`, you will *always* get 10000 ms, irrespective to time zone.